# How to Install GCC 2.95 on Ubuntu 12.0.4?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, ubuntu, compilation

I am trying to install GCC 2.95 on Ubuntu 12.0.4. Here is the error

`decl.c : in function 'start_struct':
         4449:27;  argument 'code' doesn't match prototype`

`ch-tree.h: 736:13: error: prototype declaration`

I tried:

`./configure`
`make` (Failed)

What can I do to resolve these errors and install GCC 2.95 on Ubuntu 12.0.4?

Comment: Isn't there a README file that goes through all the installation steps in the root folder of the sources...?

Comment: yes i followed but problem is its not been compiled successfully so far. attached some errors u can look over.

Comment: Why are you trying to install a decade-old compiler on a current version of Linux?  (My copy of the source for 2.95.3 has 2001-03-16 as the latest modification date, so that's comfortably over a decade.)  Which compiler version are you using to bootstrap your build?

Comment: I'm trying to use it to re-compile an old kernel for some obscure embedded system, the kernel doesn't support compiling with my oldest available compiler (GCC 4.7)

Answer (score 2):

My theory is that you are building it wrong. Did you read the directions?

I think you need to run `./configure`, then run `make bootstrap`. It has been a while (12 years at least!) but I think that will work.

The difference is that bootstrap will build a tiny version of GCC then build GCC then build GCC again. Of course this is slower than just make, but it should be able to build GCC starting with any K&R C compiler.

Comment: I tried with make bootstrap here is the result:
/usr/include/unistd.h:610: bits/confname.h: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [libgcc2.a] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/shazzad/gcc-2.95/objdir/gcc'
make[1]: *** [bootstrap] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/shazzad/gcc-2.95/objdir/gcc'
make: *** [bootstrap] Error 2 . I checked for bits/confname.h found in " usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits " but the /usr/include/unistd.h includes " bits/confname.h " like #include <bits/confname.h> ,

Comment: I don't think you can run `./configure` from the source directory on gcc 2.95. You need to do something like make your own subdirectory called build then cd into it and run `../configure`. I'm not 100% sure, as it's been some 7 years or so since I built gcc 2.95, but I seem to remember gcc used to be very picky about not building in-place in the source tree.

Comment: oh yes, i used different objdir then run "/home/gcc-2.95/configure" But from the error it is evident that /usr/include/unistd.h looking for the confname.h in to the /usr/include/bits directory but "bits" folder is at different place /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu . May be the latest versions of linux using that kind of path. really don't know how to resolve it. On which linux version u installed  gcc-2.95?